# Instantiate service automatically in servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm working with Tomcat 8.5 and creating a servlet that lists students.

Since I'm not working in a dependency injection framework, is there a way 
to tell the servlet container to instantiate `studentService` automatically?

Also, StudentService is a concrete class not an interface.

```
@WebServlet("/students")
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private StudentService studentService;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Student> students = studentService.list();
        request.setAttribute("students", students);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/students.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }  
}
```

Comment: If there was a way, you would be working inside a dependency injection framework, wouldn't you? http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/3.0.1.Final/en-US/html_single/#_deploying_to_apache_tomcat

Comment: @JBNizet okay, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something